# scroll wheel not working when mouse is moving

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, mouse, scrolling

Ubuntu 17.04/17.10 under VMWare 12.

In some windows (e.g. `gnome terminal` / `google chrome`) when the mouse is moving the scroll wheel does not work.

I tried a clean installation (17.04 with Unity/Gnome3 and 17.10 mate).

When the mouse is not moving - scrolling work fine.

Some applications (e.g. FireFox) do not have the described problem.

Google Chrome has the described problem.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: install/remove open-vm-tools-desktop not give any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit -> Preferences -> Optimize mouse for games: Always

Change this setting fix the problem.

[image: Optimize mouse for games: Always]

Comment: Any idea how to fix the problem under VirtualBox? Cannot find any such setting neither in the global nor the machine-specific settings.

Comment: Same problem here with VirtualBox. While mouse is moving, scrollwheel does not work.

Comment: I am on VMWare Player 15, I can't find preferences that look like this.

Comment: Same problem with VirtualBox, I've installed AutoScroll extension to get rid a little bit with the problem but still occurs. Firefox scroll works right...