# How to run imwheel at startup/login to allow scrolling while moving the mouse

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, mouse, vmware, ubuntu-20.04

#### Tl;dr:

Moving the mouse while rotating the scroll wheel prevents the scrolling from actually happening in most applications. imwheel helps, but how do I run it on startup or login so that it actually works?

#### In detail:

I have a Windows 10 host and an Ubuntu 20.04 guest. The guest was originally installed in VMware, but I exported it (via an OVF) to VirtualBox too, for testing. In VMware Player I am using the "not optimized for gaming" mouse setting.
I have two physical mouses attached. One is the normal mouse that controls the host OS ("Host-Mouse"). The other is passed through to the guest OS ("Guest-Mouse"). The following table shows the combinations of movement and wheeling of both mouses and what the guest OS is doing:
[image: Default]
Red means it doesn't work and it's a problem, orange means it doesn't work but it's acceptable (for me).
The problem does not occur in FireFox (so far it's the only exception I found), but in "Text Editor", "Settings", "Files" and - most problematic for me - "Qt Creator" the cursor moves but the window is not scrolled.
I found `imwheel`, which fixes the problem, but I cannot figure out the arcane rituals necessary to run it at startup or login such that it actually works.

#### Why is this so long?:

This was gonna be about the mouse wheel problem itself, but right at the end I found `imwheel`. I already wasted hours testing and writing all of this down, so while I cut it down, I don't want to let it all go to waste.

#### What I tried:

I've seen others with the same problem and no (good/applicable) solution:
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Mouse-scrolling-in-VM-guest-doesn-t-work-when-mouse-is-moving/td-p/2731610
Added those settings, no change.
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Horizon-Desktops-and-Apps/Mouse-wheel-does-not-work/td-p/2835340
Was already on, disabled and re-enabled it, no change.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080542/mouse-scroll-doesnt-work-while-moving-pointer-on-vmware-workstation-with-ubuntu
Tried EN-US keyboard layout, no change.
Tried the commands suggested by Arwez, no change.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446314/scrolling-impossible-while-moving-mouse-fedora-28-vm-guest-on-win10/498564#498564
Tried `xev | grep -n -e "ButtonPress" -e "ButtonRelease"`, I see activity from the mouse wheel while moving.
`xinput` showed "Virtual core XTEST pointer" (ID 4) and "Logitech M325" (ID 12) for both VMware and VirtualBox, and then some other slave pointers that differ between the two. I tried disabling each one individually with e.g. `xinput disable 4`:
Disabling "Virtual core XTEST pointer" errors out with "BadAccess".
In all other cases *something* was not working, but it never worked in the intended way.

#### Workaround:

[scroll wheel not working when mouse is moving](https://superuser.com/questions/1257137/scroll-wheel-not-working-when-mouse-is-moving)
Using "optimized for games" mouse in VMware and disabling mouse-integration in VirtualBox works, but it's not a great solution since that makes switching between guest and host extremely annoying.
VMware:
[image]
VirtualBox:
[image]

#### imwheel:

Taken from this answer: [Inconsistent and erratic mouse wheel in Linux while moving the mouse pointer](https://superuser.com/questions/1270811/inconsistent-and-erratic-mouse-wheel-in-linux-while-moving-the-mouse-pointer/1270812#1270812)
Running `imwheel` while already in a console, either as root or as a normal user, fixes the issue.
But none of the ways I tried to have it run automatically work:

**init.d:**
I considered adding a file to `/etc/init.d` that simply runs imwheel, but I could not find a sensible explanation of how to create such a file or what the contents that I found in existing files mean (particularly parts of the comment header).

**systemd:**
Taken from this tutorial: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-script-on-startup-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-server-desktop
I created the file `/etc/systemd/system/imwheel.service` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
After=display-manager.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/imwheel > /home/user/Desktop/imwheel.txt 2>&1
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

And ran these commands and rebooted:

```
chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/imwheel.service 
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable imwheel.service
```

The imwheel.txt file was not created.

**crontab -e:**
I added these two lines to crontab and rebooted:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/imwheel > /home/user/Desktop/imwheel.txt 2>&1
@reboot echo "a" > /home/user/Desktop/echo.txt
```

The two files are created, echo.txt contains "a", but imwheel.txt contains the following:

```
INFO: imwheel started (pid=741)
Could not open display, check shell DISPLAY variable, and export or setenv it!
```

This happens with both root and the normal user.

**Startup Applications:**
Taken from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/101197/how-can-i-make-an-application-start-up-when-i-login/101200#101200
I hit the windows key, searched for "startup applications", clicked on the only result, added a new entry with the command `/usr/bin/imwheel > /home/user/Desktop/imwheel.txt 2>&1`.
The imwheel.txt file was not created.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is actually not as easy as it should be. Creating a systemctl user unit is the right approach but you will need to find the right dependencies to wait for - imwheel will work only if the X display and session are ready. Here's the imwheel.service definition I am using in Manjaro 5.15 + KDE that works reliably to start imwheel once I log into my session:

```
[Unit]
Description=IMWheel
After=plasma-kwin_x11.service
PartOf=graphical-session.target
[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=XAUTHORITY=%h/.Xauthority
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/imwheel -kill -d
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pkill imwheel
RemainAfterExit=yes
Restart=on-failure
Slice=session.slice
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

In order to customize this script to your environment, run `systemctl --user status` and identify your window manager or something similar, look up its definition file which likely will be in `/usr/lib/systemd/user` and adapt the service definition above. Will most likely require you to change `After=`, `Slice=`, `PartOf=` and `WantedBy=` based on your environment.